# raphael.js passing parameter using the .data() method

Tags: javascript, parameter-passing, raphael

I'm trying to use the .data method on raphael.js.

```
 var r = Raphael('diagram', width, width);
 [...]
 var z = r.path().attr({ arc: [value, color, rad], 'stroke-width': width/24 });
 z.data({"entry": entry});
 z.mouseover(function(){
            this.animate({ 'stroke-width': width/14, opacity: .75 }, 1000, 'elastic');
            if(Raphael.type != 'VML') //solves IE problem
            this.toFront();
            title.stop().animate({ opacity: 0 }, speed, '>', function(){
                this.attr({ text: this.data('entry').name + '\n' + this.data('entry').value + '%' }).animate({ opacity: 1 }, speed, '<');
            });
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. Is this a bug in raphael.js, or is my code incorrect?

Please help, thank you.

How can I pass the parameter to the mouseover method?

http://jsfiddle.net/stefanszakal/St9Ky/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Raphael JS 1.5. `.data()` method on elements was not implemented.

Use this one: //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js

the fiddle works great with it.

Comment: Error message: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'data'. I've tried in all sorts of ways to get this work and no success. when I try to do z.data({"entry": entry}); I get exception. By the way, I'm running this in Chrome.

Comment: You were not using the good library version - I edited my answer

Comment: Thank you, this fixed the runtime error. But this took me back to square 1. If you look at the widget when you go with mouse over the arcs, all arcs have the same value (text in the black circle). How can I get the desired behavior? Thanks

Comment: This is not the original question. If you have another question, create a new one and close this one as answerd (but "giveme teh codez" questions are usually not appreciate.). And I don't know what is the desired behavior.

Comment: Ok, I see: in the mouseover function, add: `var entry = this.data('entry');` at the beginning and then, in the same function, instead of `z.data('entry').` use `entry.`